# Accessing implemented class method without creating object through Interface?

Tags: c#, .net, interface

I have two classes Say A and B which has method set().

```
   public Class A : I<string>
   {
      void Set(string str)
      {
         //do something
      }
   }

   public Class B : I<int>
   {
      void Set(int str)
      {
         //do something
      }
   }
```

And an interface as follows...

```
interface I<T>
{
    void Set(T param);
}
```

I would like to access this method without instantiating the classes, through interface (Is it possible or is there any other way like dependency injection?).

From another Class

```
Class D
{
    I.Set(<T> str); //something like this
}
```

So based on  data type I need to redirect the call from either interface or some where, so that if tomorrow I added a class say C which implements same interface, I should not end up with changing code in D.

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Without instances of `A` or `B` (or some future `C`), on what are you actually expecting to set values?

Comment: Without actual objects instances in memory, I'm not sure what this question is trying to achieve. You cannot call an interface like a class e.g. `I.Set()` since an interface is nothing more than a contract, it's not an actual object in memory that is instantiated.

Comment: @Mathew Abbott I have the parameter type of set method to distinguish this... My first question is, Is this possible? Or else  any other solution for this?

Comment: @LijoVarghese You misunderstand what Matthew aims at: You can not call anything on an interface, because always an object is needed to perform something.

Comment: Change set to accept object and cast inside imoemented methods to T

Comment: @BrandonSeydel Or use an extension method to get type safety even at compile time... I wrote a comment to Matthew Abbots answer why your approach is not the best choice.

Comment: The entire problem is that it cannot be done at compile time because he doesn't know what T is.  Please stop commenting on this thread as u have no idea why it even started.

Answer (score 4):

An interface is sort of like a template of methods an implementing class provides. You can not "do anything" with an interface. You always need an instance of a class implementing the interface.

So what you want does not work. However, a simple extension method will help you here:

```
public static class MyExtensionMethods
{
    public static void SetValue<T>(this I<T> intf, T value)
    {
        intf.Set(value);
    }
}
```

Using this, you can write:

```
A a = new A();
B b = new B();

b.SetValue("Hello");
a.SetValue(1);
```

And it will work for any other classes that implement `I<T>` **without having to change the extension method**:

```
public class D : I<double>
{
    public void Set(double d) { ... }
}

D d = new D();
d.SetValue(42.0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in *something*, so at the moment, my best guess would be

```
class D
{
  public void Set<T>(object target, T value) 
  {
    var instance = target as I<T>;
    if (instance != null)
    {
      instance.Set(value);
    }
  }
}
```

Called like:

```
var theD = new D();
var theA = new A();
var theB = new B();
theD.Set<string>(theA, "hello");
theD.Set<int>(theB, 1);
```

Comment: While that works it has two flaws in my opinion: a) it doesn't warn you about errors at compile time and b) it simply does nothing if you pass in invalid parameters. It just doesn't set any values. This may lead to bugs that are really a PITA to debug...